# String replacement via regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I've created some code which writes settings to a config file (for WordPress eg wp-config), and wraps this setting in comments.

Such as:

```
  # START WP_MEMORY_LIMIT
  define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '250M');
  # END WP_MEMORY_LIMIT
```

But in order to optimise my code I'm looking to drop the comments altogether and just directly write  (and later delete) the setting via a regex. Where can I start with this?

Essentially the regex would be able to identify the following string of text in the config file:

```
  define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', 'xxxxxx');
```

Where 'xxxxxx' could be any alphanumerical value.

Comment: If you do stuff like `writes settings to a config file` then write it always full, and dont replace parts of it. By the way, why not directly change this in the file?

Comment: you can look like wordpress with this regex: `/^define\('([A-Z_]+)',([ ]+)/`. Look for more infos in `admin/setup-config.php` in line 323, Your regex must be different for the second match group

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I intend to remove the full line, that's what I want the regex for. So that I can remove the line, and insert a new one.

Comment: @Sysix Interesting. I'd not considered that this might exist already. I'll  look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions why not manually edit the file? Because that´s not very userfriendly for end users.